# Why does host+curl take longer than host alone and curl alone?

Tags: dns

I tried to test the speed of my website, so I used

`time curl "http://google.com"`

The result ended with

`real   0m15.589s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s`

I tried to see what took so long, so I timed hosts
`time host google.com`

and got

`real   0m0.180s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.004s`

And `time curl "http://216.58.217.206"`

and got

`real   0m0.163s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s`

0.18 s + 0.16 s is *much* less than 15.58s!!

Why does curl take so long?

Comment: Hi. This question is probably better suited for [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). Moreover, I would add more detail. There are many, many factors that could have influenced the difference in speed. (Cached response, Cached DNS, etc)

Comment: Because you're comparing apples to oranges. There's a lot going on with an invocation of curl.

Answer (score 0):

`host google.com` only resolves an A record. `curl "http://google.com"` sends an HTTP GET request. Sending HTTP messages is much more work than resolving host names.

Moreover, both `curl "http://google.com"` and `host google.com` trigger the local DNS resolver. After the desired record has been resolved, `host` has done its work, while `curl` is just beginning to do its actual work.

In short: `curl` is a tool for HTTP. `host` is a tool for DNS. `curl` implicitly depends on DNS. `host` explictily is designed for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `curl "http://google.com"`, you are specifying the `name`; means it has loopup/resolve the `name` to `IP`(First connects to `DNS` server, resolve the `IP`) and then connects/`curl` the IP(In your case Google!). It will take some time relatively.

Now, Check the [MAN](http://linux.die.net/man/1/host) page of `host`

> "host" is a simple utility for performing DNS lookups

It is only connecting to DNS/Resolving the `name` to `IP`. That's it!

`curl "http://216.58.217.206"`, In this case, there is no need to reslove/loopup the `name`. Because, as you know you're directly giving the `IP`. So, simply connecting to google!